# I want to be able to read/edit/write other sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

My infopath form reads other lists fine, but how do I update them ?

Answer (score 0):

We need more information. Are you trying to submit to another list? If you are, you can set up multiple submits and save them for each SharePoint list. Please clarify.